# Uncaught (in promise) Error:cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:158 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal url for new iframe - firebase auth service

Tags: reactjs, firebase, process, environment

I am using firebase for signup with Gmail service. When I use `process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY`

```
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
   authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
   ...
}
```

I got an error saying that my domain is not registered, but when I used the key directly inside the config object it works as expected

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Az**aS******97_4pSLLM2C*******72g*vcd****8",
  authDomain: "app-*******.firebaseapp.com",
  ...
```

How I can make sure that the `process` does work as expected

Comment: Have your tried `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN)` and checking if the value is correct?

Comment: yes, its Successfully printing all the keys on the console

Answer (score 0):

I get the same, but eventually found the answer on the Firebase site. According to Google it is safe to use the API keys without hiding it in .env. since security is handled with Firebase Security Rules.

From the Firebase website:

> Unlike how API keys are typically used, API keys for Firebase services are not used to control access to backend resources;

Here's the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys